# dc.js setting the colour of sub bar chart

Tags: dc.js

I'm trying to set the color of a barchart in a composite chart on click but the renderlet is having problems.

```
dimensions={
    {"Data1": ["line", AppStyles.color.warning], 
     "Data2": ["line", AppStyles.color.danger], 
     "Data3": ["bar", AppStyles.color.blue]
    }
}

formatData = (data) => {
    let formattedData = [];
    for(let key in data) {
        formattedData.push({
            ...data[key],
            x: this.parseDate.parse(data[key].x)
        })
    }
    return formattedData;
}

componentDidMount(){
    let data = this.formatData(this.props.data);
    this.ndx = crossfilter.crossfilter(data);
    this.chart = dc.compositeChart(this.multiLineChartContainer);
    this.dimension = this.ndx.dimension((d) => {
        return d.x;
    });
    let minDate = this.dimension.bottom(1)[0].x;
    let maxDate = this.dimension.top(1)[0].x;

    let composeGroup = [];
    Object.keys(this.props.dimensions).map((dim,i) => {
        let grp = this.dimension.group().reduceSum((d) => {
            return d[dim];
        });
        if(this.props.dimensions[dim][0] === "bar"){
            composeGroup.push(dc.barChart(this.multiLineChartContainer)
            .group(grp, dim)
            .colors("blue")
            .centerBar(true)
            .renderlet((chart) => {
                chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on('click', (event)=>{
                    console.log("clicked rect")
                    chart.colorAccessor(function(d){
                        console.log(d.key);
                        return d.key
                    }).colors(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(Object.keys(this.props.dimensions))
                    .range(['blue', '#5C5ED7', 'red', AppStyles.color.warning]))
                })
            })
            )
        } else {
            composeGroup.push(dc.lineChart(this.multiLineChartContainer)
            .group(grp, dim)
            .colors(this.props.dimensions[dim][1])
            .useRightYAxis(true)

        );
        }
    });

    this.chart.width(this.props.width)
    .height(this.props.height)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .xAxisLabel("Cohort")
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("Left")
    .rightYAxisLabel("Right")
    .xUnits(()=>{
        return 30;
    })
    .legend(dc.legend().x(this.chart.width()- 130))
    .compose(composeGroup)

    this.chart.renderlet((chart) => {
        chart.selectAll('circle, rect.bar').on("click", (event) => {
            this.props.dataSelect(event);
          });
    });
    this.chart.xAxis().ticks(5)
    this.chart.render();
}
```

I've tried adding a renderlet to the subchart but it never gets invoked. I'm about to rerender the entire chart now and set transitionDuration to 0 just to reassign the colours. Is this really the best way to do this?

Comment: `renderlet` should get called after all transitions have completed. `pretransition` should get called before transitions start. [Documentation](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor). You have a lot of levels of code there, so it's tough to guess which part might be going wrong. I think the approach in your final renderlet, on the composite chart, is probably the safest because it is so much simpler.

Comment: However, changing colors is tricky because the chart itself also wants to change colors, so when it redraws you might lose your changes. I'd suggest that click should set some state, either global or in the data, and then have a `pretransition` handler which is able to change the bar colors *every time they are drawn* based on that state.